# Snakemake: name rule instead of target file

Tags: makefile, snakemake

Here is a short example from the advanced section of snakemake tutorial:

```
rule bwa_map:
input:
    "data/genome.fa",
    lambda wildcards: config["samples"][wildcards.sample]
output:
    "mapped_reads/{sample}.bam"
threads: 8
shell:
    "bwa mem -t {threads} {input} | samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```

Now lets say that I wrote this rule months ago and I don't remember the output file name.
My understanding is that I cannot run snakemake by invoking the rule name because this would lead to an error:

```
$ snakemake bwa_map
InputFunctionException in line 9 of Snakefile:
AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'sample'
Wildcards:

$
```

First, I don't understand why snakemake cannot use the lambda function to deduce input files from the configuration file as it is quite clear that I refer to the "samples" section.

Second, is there a workaround to this?
Because it is very easy to do with good old Makefile to just use an old Makefile and run the same bwa_map rule by typing something like

```
$ make bwa_map INPUT=data/samples/A.fastq
```

Thanks in advance for your help.
Benoist

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a rule name as a target and that rule contains wildcards, Snakemake can't know what values to use for the wildcards. This can only be determined from a concrete output file in this case.
This output file can come from a downstream rule, e.g. a real ´all´ target at the top of the Snakefile, or by providing it directly at the command line.

However if you have a proper target rule at the top of the Snakefile, there is the --until flag, which allows you to execute your workflow only until a given rule.

Regarding your make example, I am not aware of this functionality. Can you point me to the docs about this? I might add something similar to Snakemake as well.

Please also note that I just improved the error message for this case in the development version of Snakemake. It is now more informative and explains the issue.

Comment: I admit Snakemake cannot know values to use for the wildcards because you say so but I don't understand why it has to be like that. The way I see it.  As in the configuration file I define samples in the format `A: /path/to/foo.txt, B: /path/to/bar.txt`, it should be enough for a workflow program to say "ok, that's my input files, I should name the output file as ... let's go for it". Hence, the program has its inputs, outputs and instructions so it can produce the output files without the users having to know the output file names from the start